# Prerouting issue

Tags: iptables, mac-address, arp, spoofing

I have three hosts: A, B and C. Let's say host A is continuously communicating with host C (e.g. poll - response). Now, I spoof both ARP tables of host and A and C with host B and want to block communication with host C, in order to make host A communicate with host B only.

To perform redirection of traffic I used `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport <port> -j DNAT --to <host B>` but it requires the connection on host A to be shut down and then up again for the traffic to be redirected.

Is there anything missing so I dont have to stop and run the communication in host A everytime I try to spoof and redirect the traffic?

Comment: Interesting. May be conntrack is not firing because the 3 way handshake doesn't take place ? Something interesting with dmesg ?

Comment: To make this unambiguous please give the IP addresses of all involved interfaces (on all hosts); even if they are not the real addresses.

Comment: Agreeing w/ Hauke, please provide exact details so that it's easier for us to follow along w/ what you're asking.

Comment: IP addresses may be 20.0.0.1, 20.0.0.2 and 20.0.0.3 (host A, B and C) and port is 5020.